# How can we adjust the features of an airfoil?

Tags: aircraft-design, airfoil, cfd

We have a base airfoil with

- Max thickness 11.7% at 28% chord
  and
- Max camber 3.4% at 42% chord.

Say, we want to draw our own airfoil based on the previous description but with an

- increase maximum percentage of chord by +3%
  and
- increase thickness by 0.2%

Which method and software should we use?
Which position coordinates should I edit to achieve this?
I want to draw my own airfoil and run it through CFD.

Thank you in advance.